# Exporting data from local standard environment and importing it in Datastore Emulator

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

We have two app engine apps, which read/save to the same datastore (that is, same project).
Datastore is actually the way they "transfer data" to each other.

One of the apps is running on standard environment, and the other is running in the flexible environment.

In the flexible environment, to run local tests in my machine, without using google datastore servers, I have to use the Datastore Emulator, which it's configured already.

What I would like now is to find a simple way to export data saved in the standard environment app (created using dev_appserver.py) and import it in the datastore emulator.

I would NOT like to push the data google servers and export from there, if that could be avoidable, instead exporting from the database that ran in my local machine.

Is there a feature/library which might help me with this task?

Answer (score 1):

In my tests, I found that the database files created by AppEngine Dev and Datastore Emulator are compatible. I was able to copy the `local_db.bin` from app-engine database to replace the same file in Datastore Emulator's data directory and was able to access the data.

Comment: Yeah, that'd solve my problem. But in my tests, when I run `dev_appserver.py`, a file datastore.db is created with format `SQLite 3.x database`, while the datastore emulator creates a file `local_db.bin` with format `Java serialization data, version 5`. I tried copying anyways and the emulator returned me an error.
Maybe the GAE SDK for java and python behave differently when using a local emulator?

Comment: Sorry, my tests were done with Java. I was hoping that file formats would be same across all languages, but looks like that's not the case.

Comment: It was worth a try. Thanks!

Comment: @diogovk hi, where you able to do this? I am exactly at the same situation now, and would like to use datastore.db in the datastore emulator

Comment: I'm not sure that particular workflow is supported by dev_appserver.py. I know the SDK provides an emulator for Datastore... If you could make the non flexible project connect to the emulador that could work. No idea is that's possible.