# How to use the same G. Cloud Datastore for apps in standard and flexible environments?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working in a project that use two apps, one deployed in App Engine standard environment and other in flexible env.  One service of the app in the standard env and the app in the flex env. must be access to [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview).

If I use in **local** the emulated datastore that run the dev_server in standard environment, the app in the flex env. can't access to this datastore and neither use the ndb ORM library like the service in standard env.

So, to have consistency in the way to access to data, I don't what solution would be better to solve this.

I've been thinking if I could use Google Cloud SDK (gcloud tool) to run `emulators datastore` and access to this using [Cloud Datastore Cient Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) ( instead of [Google Datastore NDB Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) ) in both apps (to use exactly the same way to connect) I think that this way is most easy to develop after in cloud platform.

I'm finding some problems to connect with this emulated datastore and I would like to know if my approach is good to follow fighting with the problems or change to another way or idea to run my entire project in local.

Any help or idea will be welcome.

Comment: Somehow related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139307/exporting-data-from-local-standard-environment-and-importing-it-in-datastore-emu

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I don't want export data. I would like use exactly the same datastore to both apps through the same way to connect, like the real scenario, but in local.

Comment: I know, hence that "somehow" :)

Comment: Also good info and pointers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809756/using-google-cloud-datastore-with-ndb-api.